Life insurance check bank will not cash
Life insurance check made out to estate. No beneficiary. The will named me as beneficiary. How do I cash it? Bank will not cash

Note that generally, banks don't want to cash checks. What they want you to do is to deposit the check into an account. This guarantees that they know who you are and can recover their money should the check bounce. So deposit the check, wait for it to clear, then pull the cash out if that's really the form you need it in.

@keshlam Don't want or don't have to?

@pipe Banks don't have to cash checks for customers either; they can insist that you deposit the check and wait, or withdraw other funds if you need cash now. But they may be willing to cash a check as a sort of provisional short-term loan if they know the customer can be trusted to pay it back if the check doesn't go through. Note that this is why check-cashing businesses can get away with charging a painfully high rate for the service; they're taking much more risk since they are effectively issuing a short-term loan to someone they don't know will be able to repay it.

@keshlam less "can get away with" and more "are forced to", but yes.

I would call few local probate attorneys (or a local "free legal clinic") and see if you can get some free advice, but here's some general rules:
The executor of the estate is the one who would be able to cash the check (and deal with other assets of the estate) to distribute it to the beneficiaries listed in the will. They also have to make sure that any debts and taxes for the estate are taken care of first.  If the will does not name an executor, then the probate court can appoint one.
It's common for the sole beneficiary to also be the executor, but you have to make sure that you also pay off the debts (and taxes) of the estate before distributing assets to yourself.
The bank may also require that you set up an estate account if one does not exist so that you keep good records of the estate assets.
Those complexities are why a probate lawyer can be worth the fees (depending on the size of the estate), or can help you avoid creating a mess.

This is good advice, but there's more. If OP was the beneficiary of the life insurance policy, then the payment bypasses the estate and can be paid directly to her, with no obligation to settle the estate's debts and taxes. But if the beneficiary of the insurance policy was not named, the check properly goes to the estate and the OP is entitled to whatever remains in the estate after funeral, final medical expenses, taxes and debts are paid off.

@MTA that ship has likely sailed though...

@MTA But the first sentence says "Life insurance check made out to estate." So clearly that's not the case.

@xLeitix so long as it was correctly made out to the estate rather than a named beneficiary

@ChrisH But if it was incorrectly made out, that's not the bank's responsibility. You'd have to contact the insurance company, have them void the old check and make a new one to the correct recipient.

@R.M.of course, but the OP may need to get to the bottom of why the bank won't cash it (rightly or wrongly), to overcome the obstacle

Life insurance can be made out to a specific beneficiary.  In many jurisdictions, this makes it bypass the estate.  But this is a property of the Life insurance, not the Will.
If they have Life insurance without a beneficiary, and a Will that says the money goes to a specific person, then the Life insurance goes through the estate.
The estate is a legal entity whose job it is to wrap up the business of the deceased.  It gets all of the deceased debts and assets (and taxes due), such as life insurance without a beneficiary.  Then it pays off creditors against the estate.  If there is any assets left, it then distributes them according to either the Will or the inheritance laws of your area.
So what you need to do at this point is find the Life Insurance paperwork and see if you are listed as a beneficiary there.  If you are in the Life Insurance paperwork, then the check is made out to the wrong target - it should be made out to you directly.  Get that fixed.  (Note: be aware that you may owe taxes on Life Insurance: not where I live, but some places tax life insurance.  Before you spend it, make sure you know if you owe taxes, and put aside money to pay said taxes.)
If you aren't listed as a beneficiary on the Life Insurance paperwork itself (again, not the Will), then the check is made out the the estate correctly.
You now need an executor to execute the Will (and the estate) according to your local inheritance laws.  If you screw up, there are financial consequences.  Typically a will will name an executor.  Often executors hire lawyers to help them navigate the process, especially with more complex and larger estates.
If you are named as executor of the will, there is usually paperwork to do in order to actually become the executor.
Note that even if you are the executor and the sole beneficiary, simply taking the money and running with it will probably have legal consequences.  The part where you clear the deceased debts (and owed taxes) has to happen first, including administrative fees that the court imposes (like probate fees).
If you execute an estate and it has 0$ left in it after clearing debt (so the inheritors get nothing), you still get to claim payment as the executor (at least where I live) coming to about 5% of the assets in the estate (on which you owe income tax).
All of this is somewhat complex and has consequences if you get it wrong, which is why people often hire lawyers to help.
(The above is a layman's understanding of inheritance law within a common-law based jurisdiction.  Things may be substantially different where you live.)
